# Proper grading around the foundation

Tags: drainage

I know that the moisture problem we have is being caused by positive drainage towards the house.  I've seen recommendations for simply properly grading the soil (6 inch drop for every 10 feet) and recommending a clay soil.  The questions are these. I need to dig out a bit to get the slope I need. Does anything go underneath the soil, like gravel?  And does anything go on top of the soil, like a plastic membrane and then more gravel? Thanks.
Ron

Comment: what have you decided is the slope you need? grading may not be the only solution you have to implement and may only add small value. If you add stone or plastic, you potentially havent done anything good (meaning, the grading of the stone and plastic becomes a huge role in success). Plastic wont last, and stone is a great idea, if applied towards a properly implemented solution.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a diagram of the area, showing the slope and the basement wall? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.